# How to change value of an attribute of all entities in Core Data at once?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building application that has 'checklist' functionality. The checklist item is stored as Core Data entity. There is a 'checked' attribute stored as `BOOL` in the Datamodel as well. The view controller handling this checklist functionality is based on `UITableViewController`.

Basically, I would like to implement the `UIRefreshControl` which allow users to reset the 'checked' status of all checklist entities in Core Data. For example, all the items would be reseted and shown as 'unchecked' once user pulls down the `UITableView`.

However, `NSFetchedResultsController` only provides access to one entity at a time via `[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]`. Would there be a way to get the whole collection of entities from Core Data as `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` therefore I could enumerate all entities and change their 'checked' attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrees with coverback...lets say you want to fetch all the objects from the entity named "Test":

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSError *error;
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

fetchObjects array contains all the objects in "Test" entity

Comment: Thanks. I was focusing on using NSFetchedResultsController, and forgot that it's possible to fetch all the object directly via the managedObjectContext itself.

Comment: And then you could call  `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` on the array. But this could take a while if you have a lot of objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

[`[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchedResultsController/fetchedObjects) will do just fine for your task.

In this case it is also not needed to use `NSFetchedResultsController`, you can get away with a simple [`NSFetchRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update a lot of entities so the solution using `NSFetchRequest` were too slow. Luckily Apple added `NSBatchUpdateRequest` in iOS 8. Here's a simple example:

```
NSBatchUpdateRequest *batchUpdate = [[NSBatchUpdateRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];
batchUpdate.propertiesToUpdate = @{ @"attribute": @(0) };
batchUpdate.resultType = NSBatchDeleteResultTypeStatusOnly;
[managedObjectContext executeRequest:batchUpdate error:nil];
```

And here's a good blog post on the subject: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-ios-8-batch-updating/.